# Blender 2.91 and RTX3090

Tags: subdivision-surface

I am trying to determine if this is a blender version or hardware issue or something else:

I have 2 systems that I use for rendering:

System 1: AMD threadripper 16 core, 64gb RAM, dual 1080ti (11gb VRAM) - blender 2.79b
System 2: AMD threadripper 64 core, 128gb RAM, dual RTX 3090 (24gb VRAM) - blender 2.91.0

Scene setup:

Resolution: 12,000 x 7941
Plane with subsurf modifier, (simple, adaptive subdivision) - using an image to subdivide the plane through the subsurf modifier (image used is 12,000 x 7941, appr. 350mb)
A few spot lights and 1 HDRI
Samples: 512

I'm trying to render the same file in both systems and the file renders fine in system 1.
System 2 tells me I am running out of memory....(rendering on GPU's only).

System 2 can run GPU's in SLI (so a combined 48gb VRAM when 'distribute memory across devices' is turned on in preferences) but same memory issue when not running in SLI.

I know adaptive subdivision is 'expensive' concerning memory but given that the scene renders perfectly in 2.79b on system 1 but runs out of memory on a system that has more than double the VRAM memory (4 times considering SLI) and twice the amount of DDR RAM makes me wonder - is 2.91 really bad in handling adaptive subdivision or hardware/settings issue?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I've not seen that SLI actually gives any benefit for rendering.  We're not able to take advantage of the shared memory pool, the data must be copied to each card if I remember right.